# How to Get List of Coupons Available for Customer Using REST API

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api, coupon, sales-rule

I need to get the List of Coupons Available for Logged in customers using REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this API:

```
<route url="/V1/carts/:cartId/coupons" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: I tried using  Endpoint : /V1/carts/:cartId/coupons my response is '{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Cart::manage"
    }
}'

Comment: you need to generate authentication token to use this api

Comment: because this api is not open api else if you just want to test the response you can change from <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" /> to <resource ref="anonymous" /> and check api response